# If I am using Haskell Platform (2013.2.0.0) with GHC (7.6.3) is it okay to install Xcode 5?

Tags: macos, haskell, ghc, xcode5

I currently have Xcode 4.6.3 installed.  Today the App Store told me that Xcode 5 is available.

Should I upgrade, or will the upgrade break GHC 7.6.3?

I am looking at [ghc trac #8197](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8197) and [ghc trac #8148](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8148), and they seem to suggest that there will be problems.  Is that correct?

Comment: Maybe over the weekend.

Comment: Might be wise to avoid Xcode 5 for now: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2013-September/108902.html

Comment: @TomSavage Great! could you make your comment an answer?

Comment: Hopefully this will be patched soon, I'd really like to be able to test 7.6 in the future (currently I use ghc's head)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No it is not.**

Upgrading to Xcode 5 will break a whole mess of things. (A common one is Cabal installs)

GHC 7.6.x does not now how to use clang for a preprocessing step and it will break.

**Do not upgrade to Xcode 5 until GHC 7.8 is released.**

I did this before I started learning haskell and it was not a fun experience trying to figure out what went wrong when I tried to download cabal packages and ghc generated a 4000 line error code.

See: http://haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2013-September/108902.html

If anyone who has already downloaded Xcode 5 stumbles upon this after everything breaks, the way to fix your bug is:

1. Download the Xcode 4.6.x command line tools **from the apple developer website.**
2. Install
3. Write some killer Haskell